# Problema para linkar JFrame com a main

Tags: java

Estou querendo começar a usar o Jframe, estou com um programa de petshop (bem simples) que posso, inlcuir cliente, incluir animal, fazer serviço, consultar cliente e excluir cliente. queria fazer um menu para ele usando o Jframe, mas não faço ideia de como linkar as duas classes, segue abaixo a classe main e a Jframe.

```
package br.com.petshop.dados;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

import br.com.petshop.modelo.Animal;
import br.com.petshop.modelo.Cliente;
import br.com.petshop.modelo.Os;

public class CadastroCliente {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        // JdbcDAOFactory jdbc = new JdbcDAOFactory();

        Random r = new Random();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean menuPrincipal = true;
        Animal a = new Animal();
        Cliente c = new Cliente();
        while (menuPrincipal) {
            System.out.println("BEM VINDO AO PET SHOP ITSTEP");
            System.out.println("| Escolha a opção desejada |");
            System.out.println("|                          |");
            System.out.println("| 1 - Incluir Cliente      |");
            System.out.println("| 2 - Incluir Animal       |");
            System.out.println("| 3 - Fazer Serviço        |");
            System.out.println("| 4 - Consultar cliente    |");
            System.out.println("| 5 - Excluir Cliente      |");
            System.out.println("|**************************|");



            switch (s.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                // Incluir cliente
                System.out.println("Entre com o nome do Cliente:");
                c.setNome(s.next());
                c.setMatricula(r.nextInt(9999));
                System.out.println("Entre com o e-mail do Cliente:");
                c.setEmail(s.next());
                System.out.println("Entre com o telefone fixo do Cliente:");
                c.setFixo(s.next());
                System.out.println("Entre com o telefone celular do Cliente:");
                c.setCelular(s.next());
                System.out.println("**** Endereço ****");
                System.out.println("Entre com o nome da rua:");
                c.setLogradouro(s.next());
                System.out.println("Entre com o complemento:");
                c.setComplemento(s.next());
                System.out.println("Entre com o bairro:");
                c.setBairro(s.next());
                System.out.println("Entre com a cidade:");
                c.setCidade(s.next());
                System.out.println("Matricula do cliente: " + c.getMatricula());
                try {
                    CrudCliente ic = new CrudCliente();

                    if (ic.incluir(c.getNome(), c.getEmail(), c.getFixo(), c.getCelular(), c.getLogradouro(),
                            c.getComplemento(), c.getBairro(), c.getCidade(), c.getMatricula())) {
                        System.out.println("incluido com sucesso");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Erro na inclusão");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                menuPrincipal = true;
                c = null;
                break;

            case 2:
                // Incluir Animal

                System.out.println("Entre com o nome do animal:");
                a.setNome(s.next());
                System.out.println("Digite a Matricula do Dono:");
                a.setMatricula(s.nextInt());
                System.out.println("Digite o sexo do animal:");
                a.setSexo("Macho");
                System.out.println("Digite 1 para Cachorro e 2 para Gato:");
                String especie = "";
                boolean escolha = true;
                while (escolha) {
                if (s.next().equals("1")) {
                    especie = "Cão";
                    escolha = false;
                } if (s.next().equals("2")) {
                    especie = "Gato";
                    escolha = false;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("digite uma opção válida");
                    escolha = true;
                }
                }
                a.setEspecie(especie);
                System.out.println("Digite a raça:");
                a.setRaca(s.next());
                System.out.println("Digite o ano de nascimento com 4 digitos:");
                a.setAnoNascimento(s.nextInt());
                a.setClienteId(a.getMatricula());
                System.out.println("Digite o porte do animal:");
                a.setPorte(s.next());

                try {
                    CrudAnimal ia = new CrudAnimal();

                    if (ia.incluir(a.getNome(), a.getRaca(), a.getEspecie(), a.getMatricula(), a.getClienteId(),
                            a.getAnoNascimento(), a.getSexo(), a.getPorte())) {
                        System.out.println("incluido com sucesso");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Erro na inclusão");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
                menuPrincipal = true;
                a = null;
                break;

            case 3:
                // Serviço
                Animal animal = new Animal();
                System.out.println("Entre com a matricula:");
                animal.setMatricula(s.nextInt());

                try {
                    CrudAnimal ca = new CrudAnimal();

                    if (ca.consultar(animal.getId(), animal.getNome(), animal.getRaca(), animal.getEspecie(), animal.getMatricula(), animal.getClienteId(), animal.getAnoNascimento(), animal.getSexo(), animal.getPorte())) {
                        System.out.println("Consulta realizada com sucesso");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Erro na consulta");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception

                }
                boolean teste = true;
                Os os = new Os();
                CrudOs io = new CrudOs();
                os.setPrecoTotal(0.00);

                System.out.println("Animal correto? S/N");

                if (s.next().toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                    while (teste) {
                        System.out.println("Escolha o serviço a ser feito:");
                        System.out.println("1 - Banho");
                        System.out.println("2 - Tosa Higiênica");
                        System.out.println("3 - Tosa");

                        switch (s.nextInt()) {
                        case 1:

                            os.setMatricula(animal.getMatricula());
                            os.setPrecoTotal(os.getPrecoTotal() + 30.00);
                            os.setServico("Banho");
                            try {

                                if (io.incluir(os.getMatricula(), os.getPrecoTotal(), os.getServico())) {
                                    System.out.println("incluido com sucesso");

                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Erro na inclusão");
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                            System.out.println("Deseja mais algum serviço? S/N");
                            if (s.next().toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                                teste = true;
                            } else {
                                teste = false;
                                menuPrincipal = true;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 2:

                            os.setMatricula(animal.getMatricula());
                            os.setPrecoTotal(os.getPrecoTotal() + 15.00);
                            os.setServico("Tosa Higiênica");
                            try {

                                if (io.incluir(os.getMatricula(), os.getPrecoTotal(), os.getServico())) {
                                    System.out.println("incluido com sucesso");

                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Erro na inclusão");
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                            System.out.println("Deseja mais algum serviço?");
                            if (s.next().toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                                teste = true;
                            } else {
                                teste = false;
                                menuPrincipal = true;
                            }
                            break;

                        case 3:

                            os.setMatricula(animal.getMatricula());
                            os.setPrecoTotal(os.getPrecoTotal() + 20.00);
                            os.setServico("Tosa");
                            try {

                                if (io.incluir(os.getMatricula(), os.getPrecoTotal(), os.getServico())) {
                                    System.out.println("incluido com sucesso");

                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Erro na inclusão");
                                }

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                            }
                            System.out.println("Deseja mais algum serviço? S/N");
                            if (s.next().toUpperCase().equals("S")) {
                                teste = true;
                            } else {
                                teste = false;
                                menuPrincipal = true;
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                menuPrincipal = true;
                break;

            case 4:
                // consultar cliente
                System.out.println("Digite o Nome do Cliente ou Matricula:");
                String nome = s.next();
                Cliente cl = new Cliente();
                cl.setNome(nome);
                CrudCliente cc = new CrudCliente();
                CrudAnimal ca = new CrudAnimal();

                try {

                    if (cc.consultar(cl.getId(), cl.getNome(), cl.getEmail(), cl.getFixo(), cl.getCelular(),
                            cl.getLogradouro(), cl.getComplemento(), cl.getBairro(), cl.getCidade(),
                            cl.getMatricula())) {
                        System.out.println("Consulta efetuada com sucesso");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Erro na consulta");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                //consulta animal seguida do cliente
                try {

                    if (ca.consultar(a.getId(), a.getNome(), a.getRaca(), a.getEspecie(), a.getMatricula(), a.getClienteId(), a.getAnoNascimento(), a.getSexo(), a.getPorte())) {

                        System.out.println("Consulta efetuada com sucesso");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Erro na consulta");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
                break;

            case 5:
                //exclusao


                System.out.println("Digite a matricula do cliente");
                c.setMatricula(s.nextInt());

                try {
                    CrudCliente ec = new CrudCliente();

                    if (ec.excluir(c.getMatricula())) {         
                        System.out.println("Excluído com sucesso");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Erro na exclusão");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }


                menuPrincipal = true;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

JFrame

```
package br.com.petshop.modelo;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

import br.com.petshop.dados.CadastroCliente;

public class MenuPricipal extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MenuPricipal frame = new MenuPricipal();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public MenuPricipal() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton btnIncCliente = new JButton("New button");
        btnIncCliente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                CadastroCliente cc = new CadastroCliente();

            }
        });
        btnIncCliente.setBounds(162, 90, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnIncCliente);

        JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_1.setBounds(162, 121, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_1);

        JButton btnNewButton_2 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_2.setBounds(162, 152, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_2);

        JButton btnNewButton_3 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_3.setBounds(162, 183, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_3);

        JButton btnNewButton_4 = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton_4.setBounds(162, 214, 85, 21);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton_4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não "linka" modo de texto com modo gráfico. Toda a interface em texto que fez, precisará elaborar uma em modo gráfico, do zero. Cada menu diferente nesse modo de texto provavelmente virará uma tela ou algum painel e muitas funções serão chamadas em *listeners* de botões ou ações de outros componentes, isso dependerá muito de como você pretende construir a aplicação.

Esqueça isso de misturar esses dois modos, até porque o jar não irá mostrar nada em console quando você gerar um, executando através de 2 cliques.

Se não sabe ou não tem tanta noção assim como criar interfaces e utilizar `listeners` da API swing, recomendo que, antes de qualquer coisa, aprenda o básico sobre os componentes, layouts e ouvintes, nos links abaixo, são um pouco antigo, mas java-swing por si já é algo velho e antiquado.

- [Interfaces gráficas com Swing(caelum)](http://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-testes-xml-design-patterns/interfaces-graficas-com-swing/)
- [Interfaces Gráficas (GUIs) em Javausando Swing(pdf)](http://www.lncc.br/~rogerio/poo/04a%20-%20Programacao_GUI.pdf)
- [Documentação oficial oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html)

E claro, na tag [swing](/questions/tagged/swing)  há inúmeras perguntas sobre o tema.